# Как сделать, чтобы клиент отправлял сообщение только нужным пользователям?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Нужно, чтобы клиент отправлял сообщение только нужным пользователям, но после отправки первого сообщения происходит возникает какой-то сбой и я просто не могу нормально пользоваться командной строкой.

Есть идеи как сделать это?

Код клиента:

```py
import socket               # Импорт модуля socket
import threading            #Импорт модуля threading
import codecs
import time


def sender():
    while True:
        try:
            message = input() #Само сообщение
            addressat = input() #Адрес получателя
            umessage = addressat + " " + message #То, что получит сервер
            s.send(umessage.encode()) 
        except:
            print("Ошибка ")
    

def receiver_function():
    try:
        while True:
            global data
            data = s.recv(16384)
            print(data.decode())
    except:
        pass


s = socket.socket()         # Создание объекта socket
host = "ip сервера"  
port = 1081 # Зарезервируйте порт для обслуживания
s.connect((host, port)) 

potok_sender = threading.Thread(target=sender,)
potok_data = threading.Thread(target= receiver_function,)
potok_data.start()
potok_sender.start()
```

Код сервера (не мой, я лишь немного его подстроил под себя):

```py
import socket
import threading
import queue
import time

# Определяем константу содержащую имя ОС
# для учёта особенностей данной операционной системы
import platform
OS_NAME = platform.system()

# Константы
HOST = 'IP'
PORT = 1081

# Единственная глобальная переменная
# доступная всем потокам
run = True


def shutdown_socket(s):
    # В Linux'ах просто закрыть заблокированный сокет будет мало,
    # он так и не выйдет из состояния блокировки. Нужно передать
    # ему команду на завершение. Но в Windows наоборот, команда
    # на завершение вызовет зависание, если сокет был заблокирован
    # вызовом accept(), а простое закрытие сработает.
    if OS_NAME == 'Linux':
        s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    s.close()   
    
def reciver(client, q):
    global addressat 
    while run:
        try:
            # Здесь поток блокируется до тех пор
            # пока не будут считаны все имеющиеся
            # в сокете данные
            
            data = client.recv(1024)

            addressat = data[0:12]

            if data: # Если есть данные
                # Отправляем в очередь сообщений кортеж
                # содержащий сокет отправителя
                # и принятые данные
                q.put((client, data))
                print('{} отправил: {}'.format(client.getpeername(), data.decode()))
                print("Адресс:" + addressat)

        except:
            break # В случае ошибки выходим из цикла
    client.close() # И закрываем клиентский сокет


def sender(q, connections):
    while run:
        closed_sockets = set()
        try:
            # Получаем из очереди сообщений
            # сокет отправителя и принятые данные
            sender, message = q.get(timeout=1)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass # Игнорируем отсутствие сообщений в очереди
        else: # Если же сообщения есть
            for s in set(connections): # Обходим все сокеты
                if s == addressat: # Кроме сокета отправителя
                    try:
                        s.send(message) # И отправляем им принятое сообщение
                    except:
                        closed_sockets.add(s)
            if closed_sockets:
                with threading.Lock():
                    connections -= closed_sockets
                print("Подключено:", len(connections))
            q.task_done() # Сообщаем, что сообщение обработано


def accepter(server, connections, q):
    while run:
        try:
            # Здесь поток блокируется до тех пор, пока кто-то не подключится к серверу
            client, addr = server.accept()
        except OSError as e:
            # Если отловлена не ожидаемая ошибка закрытия серверного сокета, а какая-то другая
            if (OS_NAME == 'Windows' and e.errno != 10038) or (OS_NAME == 'Linux' and e.errno != 22):
                raise # то возбуждаем её повторно
        else: # Если кто-то подключился и создан новый клиентский сокет
            # Устанавливаем ему таймаут, чтобы считать его сбойным, 
            # если в этот сокет не будут ничего писать более 5 минут
            client.settimeout(60 * 5)
            with threading.Lock():
                connections.add(client)
            # Запускаем новый поток, выполняющий функцию receiver
            # для только что полученного сокета
            threading.Thread(target=reciver, args=(client, q)).start()
            print("Подключено:", len(connections))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Запуск...')

    # Очередь сообщений, через которую будут общаться потоки
    q = queue.Queue()
    # Множество соединений
    connections = set()

    server = socket.socket()
    server.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server.listen()

    print(u'Сервер запущен на {}\n'.format(server.getsockname()))

    # Поток получающий сообщения из очереди
    # и отправляющий их всем сокетам в множестве connections
    threading.Thread(target=sender, args=(q, connections)).start()
    # Поток принимающий новые соединения
    threading.Thread(target=accepter, args=(server, connections, q)).start()

    while True:
        command = input()
        if command == 'exit': # Если в консоли введена команда exit
            run = False # отменяем выполнение циклов во всех потоках
            break # и выходим из этого цикла
    for s in connections:
        shutdown_socket(s)
    shutdown_socket(server)
```

Comment: Начни с того, чтобы в заголовке была описана твоя конкретная проблема, а не бесполезная информация

Comment: Про консоль у Вас получается в одной строке по сути работает и отправка и получение из за этого непредсказуемое поведение. Проще всего решается каким ни будь UI, или в консоли поочередной отправкой и получением что не всегда удобно.

Answer (score -1):

Можно сохранять список пользователей в кортеж, далее делать send to перебором кортежа
:)

Comment: уточняйте свой комментарий , а не озвучивая "общие рекомендации"

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]